# Android SMS verification SafetyNet not working from Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, safetynet

I have application in Google Play wit phone number verification.
But when I install it from Google Play then it write "This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither safetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded."

When i download apk files from play console (Original package and Package for distribution)
then with Original package its working fine but with Package for distributions it write this error message.

So all is activated and set as needed (I think) only one difference that I'm using same keystroke file for debug and for release.

Application is writen in Cordova

Thank for every suggestion

Comment: In differences between apks I see that google change my META-INF/CERT.DSA to his GOOGPLAY.RSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in certificate, as google re-sign app by its own certificate.
In that case the solution is to go to

**Play Console->Your App->Setup->App Integrity**

There you will see **App signing key certificate** and **Upload key certificate**

**Upload key certificate** is your "Debug" certificate that mostly you already have in Firebase Console, so now you need to add **App signing key certificate** to Firebase Console too.